# Wordpress: get current_post index number in WHILE loop

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

How to get current post `index number` inside WHILE loop?

```
$index_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
while ( $index_query->have_posts() ) : $index_query->the_post();

    // echo current post index number

endwhile;
```

Have tried with the following, but no result.

```
$index_query->post->current_post;
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use

```
$index_query->current_post;
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties

Answer (score 6):

I can get by using this code

```
$wp_query->current_post
```